# ListData.svc not getting managed metadata

Tags: development, list, managed-metadata, listdata.svc

I have written a C# agent that pulls data from SharePoint using the ListData.svc web method, parses the XML data, then puts it in SQL and it works great, however ListData.svc does not appear to expose the managed metadata.

Through my research I have come to understand that this is a limitation on this web service (although I do not understand why), but I have been unable to uncover another method I can use in order to pull out all the data I need.

Does anybody know of any way this can be done via C#?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that this is a limitation and a bit of a pain.  In the past I have used XSLT to put the data on the screen and if needed, hidden it and scraped it into an array for manipulation using jQuery.  If you go this route then XSLT can help by pre-formatting the data and adding classes etc.

Note that I use client-side stuff only so there may be a better way using 'real code' or even the Object Model.